# Angular Error: angular.js:4057Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

thanks for your consideration.

Now I've downloaded angular project from git, and am going to execute in my local.

I am using like below.

- node v5.10.1
- npm 3.8.3
- gulp 3.9.1
- angular 1.3.0-rc.2

By the way, at browser debug tool I got below error.

```
angular.js:4057Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3…apis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A19)
```

I'd like to know why this is happened , and how I can fix it.

Thank you for your any kind of help.

Comment: Copy/Paste that URL and it'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. What url do you mean?

Comment: Look at the browser debug error you got. Angular builds debug links so you can visit them for more information.

Comment: I've seen it, but I can't guess unfortunately.
If possible, would you explain for me in detail?
I assume you can fix it.